# Hadoop Sequence File Compression

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When trying to run a job, I get the following error:

```
SequenceFile doesn't work with GzipCodec without native-hadoop code!
```

I have read in several places that I need to get the native-hadoop code, however that is a pain for me to install.  It would be nice, if there is a parameter I can set somewhere(core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-site...ect)  and just restart hdfs.

I have tried setting the following properties in the mapred-site.xml without any luck:

```
mapred.map.output.compress.codec
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec
```

Is there a way to change this from Gzip to another compression format that does not require native-code?

Hadoop version: CDH 5.2.0
OS: CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LZO or Snappy https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-snappy/ for  compressing your data. You should add these configurations to your mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

Comment: That link talks about setting the compression class in the code.  I was wondering how to set it so that every job gets the same compression class.  Is this something that can be set in mapred-site.xml?  If so, what properties need to be set in order for this to work?